# xamarin.Android exception "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."

Tags: xamarin.android

If I use AndroidClientHandler in my Xamarin.Android project I am getting "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found." Any idea on how to avoid this error for API call

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke a local secure web service from your application running in the  Android emulator,then you can try to bypass the certificate security check.

This can be accomplished when using both the managed and native network stacks on iOS and Android, by setting the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` property on a `HttpClientHandler` object to a callback that ignores the result of the certificate security check for the local HTTPS development certificate:

```
// This method must be in a class in a platform project, even if
// the HttpClient object is constructed in a shared project.
public HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
    {
        if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
            return true;
        return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
    };
    return handler;
}
```

For more details, you can check document: [Bypass the certificate security check](https://Bypass%20the%20certificate%20security%20check).

Comment: For development purpose, I could bypass the certificate security check. Is this an acceptable solution to bypass the certificate security check for production environment? What are things we should consider or include if we would like to use AndroidClientHandler instead of using HttpClientHandler?